# What are the elements in this set $(-\infty, 4] \cap \mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I believe the answer would be $\{1,2,3,4\}$ since $\mathbb{N}$ means natural numbers and there can't be any negative integers?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your answer

Comment: Be aware that some conventions follow that $0 \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: That's good to hear, I saw a different answer somewhere and got tripped up.

Comment: Odd, I thought the whole numbers were the integers 0 through infinity and the natural numbers were all positive integers? @AryamanMaithani

Comment: @SomeGuy: but that is not a standard convention. In some settings, it actually is more natural to include $0$ in naturals.

Comment: @SomeGuy Unlike $1+1 = 2$, which is true for everyone, notational conventions like "natural numbers" aren't universal.  Similarly, some people hold $1$ is a prime number while most don't, and a bit more abstract but also more controversial, some people assume rings have a $1$ while others don't.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection denoted, $\cap$, refers to the elements in common between both sets.

In this problem, you are asked, what is the intersection of $(-\infty, 4]$ and $\mathbb{N}$ (natural numbers $0,1,2,3,4 \ldots)$

The numbers in common between the two sets are  $\{0,1,2,3,4 \}$